# Refactor an ugly loop into LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following peace of code, that factors an `int` to prime numbers:

```
    private static IEnumerable<int> Factor(int input)
    {
        IList<int> result = new List<int>();

        while (true)
        {
            var theSmallestDivisor = GetTheSmallestDivisor(input);
            if (theSmallestDivisor == 0)
            {
                result.Add(input);
                return result;
            }

            result.Add(theSmallestDivisor);
            input = input/theSmallestDivisor;
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for hints on how to improve it, possibly using LINQ.

Comment: Whats wrong with the loop you have? I don't see LINQ helping here. You aren't writing a query.

Comment: New shiny hammer (LINQ)... everything looks like a nail :)

Comment: Well LINQ is not just about queries, despite the name. The current code is 14 lines, if there is a 1 line LINQ alternative I'd be very happy.

Comment: @john_mm granted, but it is *primarily* used for queries. Even functions like `Union`, `Cast` and `OfType` are query related. The only one that comes to mind that isn't is `ForEach`. That being said, you are correct (though I still think LINQ is not useful here).

Comment: What is `GetTheSmallestDivisor()`? Where is it defined?

Comment: If not LINQ I believe an implementation using `yield` would be possible, that would eliminate the manual list management.
        `private static int GetTheSmallestDivisor(long input)
        {
            var floor = (int) Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(input));

            return Enumerable.Range(2, floor - 1).FirstOrDefault(i => input%i == 0);
        }`

Comment: Linq is for traversing collections, and you don't have one. If you had a collection of primes (or an iterator with yield) and a suitable aggregation function you could traverse it to return a single value using Fold() or First(). If my grandma had wheels she'd be a bicycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an iterator version:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Factor(int input)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var theSmallestDivisor = GetTheSmallestDivisor(input);
        if (theSmallestDivisor == 0)
        {
            yield return input;
            yield break;
        }

        yield return theSmallestDivisor;
        input = input / theSmallestDivisor;
    }
}
```

LINQ would only make this code less readable in that particular case.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, that looks quite good. I'm wondering if there's a way to eliminate the `input = input / theSmallestDivisor` assigment and have a more functional like program with immutable values.

Comment: Well... perfect is the enemy of good, and this is pretty good enough IMO. If you want functional style, you'd have to use recursion, which will both be slower, prone to stack overflows, and more difficult to read, or do something convoluted to avoid recursion. Oh, and you could use `input /= theSmallestDivisor;` if you prefer ;)

Answer (score 3):

LINQ's operators are mostly designed to generating a new list from an existing list. e.g.

```
IEnumerable<B> LinqOperator(this IEnumerable<A> list, ...)
```

Not so much for generating a list from scratch as you a trying to do.

But, since you are returning IEnumerable, you may as well make it lazy:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Factor(int input)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var theSmallestDivisor = GetTheSmallestDivisor(input);
        if (theSmallestDivisor == 0)
        {
            yield return input;
            yield break;
        }

        yield return theSmallestDivisor;
        input = input/theSmallestDivisor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetFactors(int input)
{
    int first = Primes()
        .TakeWhile(x => x <= Math.Sqrt(input))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => input % x == 0);
    return first == 0
            ? new[] { input }
            : new[] { first }.Concat(GetFactors(input / first));
}
```

Comment: Where does `Primes` come from?

Comment: You really think is *better* than the given example? More clever maybe, but it isn't really the same algorithm, and is very hard to understand/read.

Comment: Thanks a lot Darshana. I'll play a bit with your code. I already have a way to implement `Primes`: `Enumerable.Range(2, 3000).Where(i => Enumerable.Range(2, Math.Max(0, i - 2)).All(i1 => i%i1 !=0))`.